# How do I have a canvas box on top of a canvas box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to have two canvas squares on top of each other. I know how to draw on canvas but I need to know how I can put a canvas on top of a canvas specifically. I tried setting a potion but it did not work.

```
<canvas id="Canvas1" width="350" height="300"
style="border:6px solid black;">
</canvas>

<canvas id="Canvas2" width="350" height="300"
style="border:6px solid black;">
</canvas>
```

Those just want to be separated no matter what I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "I tried setting a potion but it did not work."?

```html
<canvas id="Canvas1" width="350" height="300"
style="border:6px solid black; position: absolute; left: 50px;">
</canvas>

<canvas id="Canvas2" width="350" height="300"
style="border:6px solid red;">
</canvas>
```

Comment: You answered it, that is exactly what I was looking for! I am a real noob and I make dumb mistakes a lot. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You need to have them both inside a div with `position: relative`, then set the positioning of both the canvases to `absolute`. They will then both be positioned at the top left corner of the container. Use `z-index` to specify which is in top, and `left` and `top` to tweak positioning.

```html
<div style="position:relative">
<canvas id="Canvas1" width="350" height="300"
style="border:6px solid black; position: absolute">
</canvas>

<canvas id="Canvas2" width="200" height="200"
style="border:6px solid black; position:absolute">
</canvas>
</div>
```

Note I resized the second one to show the positioning better.

Comment: So close to what I needed, I wish I could mark this one as correct too but A.Meshu has shown me how to position a canvas on top of a canvas. This info is very handy too, thank you!